# jQuery gives header negative position on first load

Tags: jquery, css

I am using some jQuery that makes a fixed header stop when reaching a div with class="bumper".
When I've tried this out locally I have had NO problem. However, now, for some reason the header is set at the begging to -220px (says by element.style when i inspect element) when cached (if you f5-reload the page) there is no problem with this.
What is causing this problem?

Here is a link to the page:
http://www.carlpapworth.com/development/utt.se/index.html

Here is the CSS:

```
header{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
background-image: url(../images/milkBG.png);
z-index: 3000;
padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//stop-header\\
    var windw = this;
    $.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
        var $this = this,
            $window = $(windw),
            $bumper = $(elem),
            bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
            thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
            setPosition = function(){
                if ($window.scrollTop() > (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                    $this.css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                    });
                } else {
                    $this.css({
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: 0
                    });
                }
            };
        $window.resize(function()
        {
            bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
            thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
            setPosition();
        });
        $window.scroll(setPosition);
        setPosition();
    };
    $('header').followTo('.bumper');
});
```

Comment: I should add that when reloading with ctrl+r it works fine in firefox, not in chrome however. When reloading with ctrl+shift+r it reverts to the bug.

Comment: Have you tried using $(window).load instead of $(document).ready? If Chrome tries to get the height of elements with images in before they're loaded, it returns 0 height and that can mess things up.

Comment: No, I'll try this out.

EDIT: Tried it out, works splendidly! Thank you so much!